# Is it possible to login onto a remote machine with a misconfigured sshd configuration file?

Tags: ssh

So basically I was stupid enough to write possibly incorrect options on my sshd configuration file. Instead of restarting the service and check whether the new configuration works, I rebooted the machine, automatically logging me out (I know...). Now when I try to ssh onto this machine, I am refused the connection. I suspect the ssh server could not be started, or could not be started properly, because of an incorrect configuration. I am wondering if there is any chance that I can use ssh (or an alternative protocol) to use this machine remotely so that I can fix the problem.

It would also be helpful to know how to prevent incorrect options, for instance regarding chroot'ing a particular user, from rendering the full ssh functionality useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If SSH is your only way to access the server, you are likely screwed. However, there *might* be other options, but you have to know what's available on your machine.

Some options to check:

- Web based control panel, e.g. Webmin or CPanel
- Remote console
- Rescue system of your provider
- Management system like Puppet (if it doesn't use SSH itself).

Comment: Fortunately I have the server physically available to me, but no monitor hooked or easily available. At worst it will take me a day to get it fixed connecting a monitor and keyboard. I don't think I have anything other than SSH available.

Answer (score 1):

> Fortunately I have the server physically available to me

Remove the hard drive, attach it as external USB or something like that, edit SSH config and be happy.

Or insert a live CD, Knoppix for example.

If it is a mac, you can start it in Firewire hard disk mode and access directly from another mac.

Comment: While this solves the problem (actually, I have already fixed it by attaching the HD to the SATA cable of another machine) it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: well, the title question or the extra in the text? if sshd is not running, you cannot ssh into the machine. but if you have other services running, you can use those. also some tools have an option to dry-run the config to see if it is okay, not sure about sshd.

Comment: you can also add an init script to open an ssh tunnel from your server to another server. this does not rely on sshd, only ssh, and you can use the tunnel to access your server.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server and what kind of connectivity options it has. If it has a separate network administration system like iDrac, then it is usually connected to network via its own IP address and you can connect to it, and then open a serial console connection to the actual console of the OS.

If you have no remote control functionality in the server, and no other remote access software in the OS, then the answer is no, you cannot access it.